# adds php data with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have this code:

My mysql table 'countries' contains the columns:
id and name

```html
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
   
<input type="hide" name="id_country" id="id_country" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('#country').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"fetch.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{query:query},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    result($.map(data, function(item){
                            return item;
                        }));
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
//fetch.php
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE '%".$request."%'
";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[] = $row["name"];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

The above code is a demo, the full version is [here](http://www.itidabhoi.org/demo/autocomplete-texbox-with-typeahead-php-ajax/)

How can I import the country id and insert it into the id_country input?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a change listener and use it to assign the ID when a change fires on the typeahead input element.

```
$('#country').change(function(ev){
    var id = ($(this).typeahead("getActive") || {}).id;
    $('#id_country').val(id);
});
```

PS: You also have to change

```
$data[] = $row["name"];
```

to

```
$data[] = $row;
```

so that the ID is also part of the JSON encoded data which then should look like:

```
[{ "id": 1, "name": "Australia"}, { "id": 2, "name": "Germany"}]
```

Comment: Where do I add your code and how do I get the id for the php country?
Thank you!

Comment: The first part needs to be added in the $(document).ready block

Comment: I made the suggested changes but the console is red: Uncaught TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function
    at Typeahead.matcher (bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1)
    at bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1
    at Function.grep (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Typeahead.process (bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (full_page.php:195)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Can you check in the network tab of your developer tools what is being returned by fetch.php and post the contents here?

Comment: I've solved the console errors. We had an error in fetch.php. It works partially, does not insert the id. I put the alert (id) for the test and return undefined to the alert.

Comment: Hm I mocked the data locally and it worked for me. Can you confirm that ‘id’ is present on the items returned by fetch.php?

Comment: my fetch.php return: Notice: Undefined index: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\fetch.php on line 13 
[{"Id":"1","name":"France"}, {"Id":"2","name":"Austria"}, ......]

Comment: id has a capital I. Can you change to  var id = $(this).typeahead("getActive").Id; and try again?

Comment: I tried and did not work, the console shows the errors from comment three and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.php:199)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: Mind posting the whole content of your script?

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function(){
$('#country').typeahead({
source: function(query, result) {
$.ajax({
url:"fetch.php",
method:"POST",
data:{query:query},
dataType:"json",
success:function(data) {
result($.map(data, function(item){
return item;
}));}
})
}
});
$('#country').change(function(ev){
var id = $(this).typeahead("getActive").Id;
$('#id_country').val(id);
});
});
</script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166349/discussion-between-jan-wendland-and-sterica-capatina).

Comment: I solved
I added to the result
result($.map(data, function(item){ 
var id = data["Id"]; 
$('#id_autoritate_contractanta').val(id); 
return item;

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in the same query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (country_id) SELECT id FROM table";
```

just change the table value

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('#id_country').val(<country-code>);
```

For this you have to return both country name and id from PHP. When user selects the country you can trigger the click event to insert the selected country id value into input.